# After effects workflow for several similar clips

Tags: after-effects, workflow

I have to create animations that will be displayed on a screen when a player scores.
Each player will have his own animation (with a photo and his name).

But all the animations will essentially be the same : a title, then the photo, then the name.

Do you have any idea what is the best workflow for doing this kind of "reusable" clips ? Maybe with placeholders ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

You can link objects in After Effects to .csv files (as well as many other formats).

For example, if you make a spreadsheet like the one below, and save it as a .csv file:

[image]

You can drag the .csv file into your project, then drag it into each comp, and then choose which line of text to use in each object using an expression like this:

```
thisComp.layer("After Effects csv test - Sheet1.csv")("Data")("Outline")("Name")("Name 0")
```

So in the example sheet shown, the text displays as "Apple", because it counts from zero after the label row.

[image]

This is old but well worth your time - Chain Rendering by Felt Tips:
https://vimeo.com/9914517

And also [Work with Data-driven animation](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/data-driven-animations.html) shows how you can use a .csv file to link to text strings and image files in your comps.

Comment: Hi Tom,
Great, that's some really useful resources !

I'll check this out. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This question and excellent @tomh 's answer shows the importance of being organized from your folder files structure first. If you name your photos with the right player name you can get the text for your text layer from the layers names photos. You can also duplicate a first one made comp and hold alt to drag-and-replace the photos without losing the animation keyframes to speed up even more the process.